# HAML doesn't change _ to -

Tags: html, pug, haml

I have haml file with this line

`.class{ aria_hidden: "true" }`

and after compile haml create

`<div class="class" aria_hidden="true">`

Why haml doesn't change `_` to `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your HAML config file: `hyphenate_data_attrs: true;`.

> [HAML documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#hyphenate_data_attrs-instance_method)
>
> **#hyphenate_data_attrs**
>
> If set to true, Haml will convert underscores to hyphens in all Custom Data Attributes As of Haml 4.0, this defaults to true.